# Assign custom keys to keyboard media buttons

Tags: windows, keyboard, media

I've a Microsoft Wireless 800 keyboard that has media keys such as Play/Pause, Volume Up/Down/Mute, etc. But it doesn't have any for Previous/Next song/video/whatever. I'm looking to map a couple of standard keys (Scroll lock and Pause Break in particular) to the above ones.

Is there an app that lets me do that ? I'd also like the ability to toggle the custom mapping.

Answer (score 5):

[AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com) is definitely the way to go on this.

Superb remapping, and a very easy syntax. You can also easily toggle the mapping per-app or using one of the keyboards "toggle keys" (such as num lock, etc).